# Scapy3 on Windows 7

Tags: scapy

I am trying to explore scapy3 on a Windows7 platform and was successful with installing the required packages. I am a beginner in this tool and I am trying a few examples from the
documentation page. I understand that scapy3 on a Windows platform is still under testing, but here in my organisation we use Python3.4 on a Windows platform and hence the need to
try this tool on a Windows platform.
  To start with a very basic step, I was able to create a IP packet with some destination address, but when I execute the show() command, I get the following error.

"

```
In [9]: IP().show()
    ←[0m###[←[0m ←[31m←[1mIP←[0m ←[0m]###←[0m
    ←[34mversion←[0m←[0m=←[0m ←[35m4←[0m
    ←[34mihl←[0m←[0m=←[0m ←[35mNone←[0m
    ←[34mtos←[0m←[0m=←[0m ←[35m0x0←[0m
    ←[34mlen←[0m←[0m=←[0m ←[35mNone←[0m
    ←[34mid←[0m←[0m=←[0m ←[35m1←[0m
    ←[34mflags←[0m←[0m=←[0m ←[35m←[0m
    ←[34mfrag←[0m←[0m=←[0m ←[35m0←[0m
    ←[34mttl←[0m←[0m=←[0m ←[35m64←[0m
    ←[34mproto←[0m←[0m=←[0m ←[35mip←[0m
    ←[34mchksum←[0m←[0m=←[0m ←[35mNone←[0m
    ←[34m←[4m←[1msrc←[0m←[0m=←[0m ←[35m←[4m←[1m0.0.0.0←[0m
    ←[34m←[4m←[1mdst←[0m←[0m=←[0m ←[35m←[4m←[1m127.0.0.1←[0m
    \←[34moptions←[0m\

In [10]:"
```

I see that this could be some kind of encoding / decoding issue. Have anybody tried this and come across this issue?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is not an error. Your terminal is printing the ANSI sequences that are used to format the outpout (colors mostly). It seems that [some people experienced the same issue](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/issues/118/scapy-win-raw-ansi-escape-sequences). I'm not sure which scapy3 you're talking about. The [secdev one?](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy3-prototype2) Or [scapy3k?](https://github.com/phaethon/scapy)